# How can I trigger the welcome email to users who didn't activate the account?

Tags: partner-communities

It seems we set up a number of  users and pushed them a welcome email but didn't note the expiration date on the link.

The link expired for may users before they were able to set the initial password.

Now when the user tries to use the password reset function or I try to trigger the password reset from within the user, the password reset email is not being sent.

The log files show this email is sent but have confirmed with over 20 users that they are not getting it.

The only way i can think of to trigger the welcome email is to disable the user and then enable a new one but as these are partner users, I must then update their username to a unique value which is problematic.

Any suggestions to trigger this welcome email again to these users?  Thanks.

Comment: Have they checked their Spam folders? Did you check your local mail server to see if they were quarantined?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your deliverability settings is not set to "no access"
[image]